# Adding Search Links to Google Sitemaps

Tags: url, seo, sitemap

Our CMS has tags-system URLs like this: .../articles/category?tag=186

Not SEO-friendly...

Rather than hack those into SEO-friendly URLs (/tag/politics/) ...

I had an idea:

1) disallow: /articles/category? (robots.txt)

2) add search URLs to our sitemap:

.../search?query=politics [which is almost the same as tag=politics]

I'm not asking about parameters (query=politics) in the URL, I know that's not ideal.

But apart from that, is this a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend adding search URLs to a sitemap; you're opening up a Pandora's Box of low value and duplicate content. I've seen this happen multiple times before on a variety of sites. G explicitly recommends you only add clean, complete (i.e. not variable/dynamic search/filter results) to your sitemap.

If the G spiders see that form of URL being explicitly asked to be indexed they might start indexing shedloads of them that you didn't initially want, which will make your problems worse, not better.

You'd honestly be better off hacking the URLs into shape with a bit of mod_rewrite and httpd.conf work (if you're using Apache), even though it's more effort at the initial stage.

Comment: Ok.. but why is a search URL of low value? Isn't a page xx.com/search/golf a better place to put a golf ad than a story about "golfer" tiger woods that took place at a "golf" club but does not really appeal to golfers?

Comment: Btw: mod_rewrite won't work as there is no simple mapping between tags & tag ids. You need to look em up in the DB. So either we have 30k rewrite rules, or we do lots of hacking in the code..

Comment: Google doesn't like to list "search" based URLs and will generally index loads of them but devalue them to the secondary index. 

Not sure I get the first point - is the the tag-system simply for ads, or for the architecture of your site?